# Share colors between CS5 programs (Fireworks, Photoshop, Illustrator, Indesign, ..)

Tags: color-profile, adobe-creative-suite

I'm looking for a good workflow to use the same colors in, for example, a new file in InDesign or Illustrator.

is there a "best practice" workflow to use the same colors in different programs?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/938/is-there-a-way-in-adobe-creative-suite-to-share-palettes-swatches-across-progr

Answer (score 6):

Create swatches (in whatever App you start in) then export swatches as an .ase file.

[image: ase save]

In every other app you can load the .ase file into swatches.

[image: load 1]

### .

[image: load 2]

### .

[image: load 3]

.ase files can be loaded into any Adobe app which uses swatches.

Web sites such as Adobe's [Kuler.com](https://kuler.adobe.com) will also allow you to save themes in an .ase format.

Comment: ColourLovers.com also allows you to download palettes as ASE.

Comment: Dribbble also lets you download ASE files.