# Dynamic color theme accros multiple documents on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I would like to have the ability to link dynamic colors to elements. Specifically, I'd like to color an element with `color 1` in several documents, so that if I decide to change `color 1`'s value from red to blue, all elements colored in my documents with `color 1` will turn from red to blue.

This is exactly what you have in CSS+HTML, the HTML code doesn't specify colors, but color variables that are then affected a given color. My question is: how do you create the ilustrator equivalent to the CSS file? (the place where you give values to color variables).

I guess this is very easy to do but I can't find the information online (I'm probably missing the right keywords).

The only solution I found for now is to do it manually by selecting some elements and remapping (inside the selected set of elements) from one color to another. I'm looking for a way to do this in a dynamic way.

PS, It would be interesting to have the same thing with fonts specifications.

Comment: Ah I found the answer here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZ3uMZrtgME (around 9:12). The solution is to check "convert process to global" when creating a new color group, then once you want to replace a color by another you simply: i) go to swatches, ii) add a new color to the group, iii) select it, iv) press `cmd` then click the color you want to replace,  v) in swatches menu select "merge swatches".

Comment: I'm still looking for a way to make this work across multiple documents (share swatches).

Comment: Ah ok, that part is easy, the answer is [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/939/118112)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty easy *within a single file*. **You can't really do this across multiple files.** At least not that I'm aware of. You **can save swatch libraries**, and then open those libraries in other files, allowing you to transport swatches between files. However, there's really no such thing as "edit one file and other files change" beyond standard file linking which is more encompassing than merely color use.

---

To do this in a single file, all you need do is use **Global Color Swatches**.

Create swatches of your colors.

[image]

With *no artwork selected* highlight the swatches in the Swatch Panel and using the Swatch Panel Menu, choose `Swatch Options...`

[image]

When the Swatch Options dialog pops up tick the **Global** checkbox and then OK.

[image]

Note how the swatches now have a small white triangle in the lower right corner. The triangle indicates a Global Swatch.

[image]

Now simply create your objects, filling them with your global swatches, or recolor what you already have using the global swatches.

[image]

Once the artwork is created/colored, you can easily alter...

With *nothing selected*, **double click one of the global swatches**. The Swatch Options for that color will appear. You can then change the color and all artwork using that color will update to reflect the color change.

[image]

---

Once you have your swatch library, you *can* use `Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork` as well.

This question may be helpful: [How to change colour of all elements of a group, at once, in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/how-to-change-colour-of-all-elements-of-a-group-at-once-in-illustrator)

And you can use `Color Harmonies` as well. It can get pretty in-depth. Here's Adobe's help on using the various color features: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/color-groups-harmonies.html There's merely too much to go into here.

Comment: You are totally right, the export is not linked to the original palette and therefore changes are not passed to the files that imported the palette (the export is a static palette).

Comment: Yeah, you can move colors between files, but you can't associate multiple files to a separate, independent, color group or file. It would be nice if what you want were possible, I just don't think it is.

Comment: @ChristianG. Developpers undertand file inheritance, but generally most non technical persons do not. Its a support nightmare in a even smallish company with shared assets. Ive been supporting such systems and its not pretty. However if you wish then a script making the syncing could be made.

Comment: I really think everyone can understand abstractions. I don't know much about Illustrator, but from what I have seen so far (symbols/link/palettes) the problem probably comes from the tool itself. If they had an intuitive (and working)  way to manage object/layers/colors/font abstractions, i'm pretty sure many people would be using it. But I can trust you when you say it's a nightmare with the current version of Illustrator.